# How to send/receive raw ethernet packets from `eth0` to `eth1`?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, scapy

I created a docker container and connected it to two bridge networks as:

```
# network 1
docker network create --driver=bridge network1 --subnet=172.56.0.0/24

#network 2
docker network create --driver=bridge network2 --subnet=172.56.1.0/24

docker run \
    --name container \
    --privileged \
    --cap-add=ALL -d \
    -v /dev:/dev \
    --network network1 \
    -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules \
    container-image tail -f /dev/null

docker network connect network2 container
```

Then, I add a bridge NIC to connect `eth0` to `eth1` and add IP address to it:

```
# creating bridge NIC
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
brctl addif br0 eth1
ifconfig br0 up

# adding IP address to br0
ip addr add 172.56.0.3/24 brd + dev br0
route add default gw 172.56.0.1 dev br0
```

Now, If I run `ip addr`, this is my output:

```
2: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:42:ac:38:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.56.0.3/24 brd 172.56.0.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6773: eth0@if6774: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:38:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.56.0.2/24 brd 172.56.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6775: eth1@if6776: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:38:01:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.56.1.2/24 brd 172.56.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Now, I'm trying to send a raw ethernet packet by using `scapy` as:

```
from scapy.all import *
import sys

src_mac_address = sys.argv[1]
dst_mac_address = sys.argv[2]

packet = Ether(src = src_mac_address, dst = dst_mac_address)

answer = srp(packet, iface='eth0')
```

It sends the packet, but it would not be received by the other side. I checked the traffic by using `bmon`, So I see the packet coming out of `eth0`, but it is never going to be received by the `eth1`. Is something wrong here? I appreciate your help. By the way, I chose `src` and `dst` MAC addresses as: `src_mac_address = 02:42:ac:38:00:02` for `eth0` and `dst_mac_address = 02:42:ac:38:00:02` for `eth1`.